# Can I use deepfake to rotoscope for animation?

Tags: game-ai, deepfakes

I'm a big fan of animation and have kept an eye on the deepfake's ability to replicate full body motion.

So I ask

1. Is there a deepfake software available I can use to gather animation from a video?
2. Are there publically released a deepfake body tracking tools out there? Even for normal video

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! Please, ask just one question per post. What do you precisely mean by "gather animation from a video"?